# Deadlocks in Actor based Programming languages

Tags: scala, erlang, deadlock, actor

Can a deadlock still occur in actor-based languages like Scala or Elixir? If yes, how to detect and avoid them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Erlang it is possible. You can have 2 processes both waiting for the other to send a message. In general, this is not a major issue.

but in most cases, you would have to work to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Scala is not an actor-based languages. Akka is just a library (and it is often misused IMHO).

Deadlock can occur because you can run arbitrary code inside `receive` method.
To prevent it - don't use any blocking/synchronization inside an actor code directly and don't call external objects' methods that use blocking inside.